# Touch command in fscrawler

Tags: elasticsearch, touch, fscrawler

I am using FScrawler to index my documents. I want to know how to use touch command whenever I add new documents to the folder. or will it be automatically indexed?

Answer (score 0):

FSCrawler needs for now to be able to detect if a file needs to be indexed since the last run. It uses for that the last modification date of the file.
Depending on the OS this date might be kept when moving files.
If you copy the file though the os will consider it as a new file.

You can also force FSCrawler to reindex all again by using the restart option.